# How does one implement large file downloads via node streams that handles WiFi loss during downloading?

Tags: node.js, download, node-streams

I'm trying to download very large files with a bit of fault-tolerance with node.js readable streams.

I've tried something like: retry-request but this doesn't handle a dropped WiFi connection. The stream is never resumed, and calling .resume() does not work.

How do you restart a large file download stream when your internet connection goes out in the middle?

If you initiate the following using [request](https://github.com/request/request#promises--asyncawait), and then turn your WiFi off and then on again the stream just sits there.

```
const request = require('request');

request(some-url).pipe(some-write-stream);
```

Comment: This isn't a problem with streams in Node.js, this is a problem for the higher level protocol you're using... and you didn't tell us anything about that.

Comment: @Brad added a simple example.